# Non EU citizen holding Romania resident permit: Transit Schengen states (without visa) to UK?

Tags: schengen, transit, indian-citizens

Situation: Indian national wanting to transit between UK and Romania. (Holding valid visas for both countries.) 
Question: Is it permitted to transit Schengen states (by car) without Schengen visa?
Thank you!

Comment: You hold a UK visa and a Romania visa but not a Schengen visa, and you want to drive from UK to Romania?

Comment: I hold a UK visa and a Romania long term resident permit. I am told that some Schengen countries accept the RO resident permit in lieu of visa, some do not. So, confused...

Answer (score 3):

No, you may not, because you don't have a Schengen visa.